# How to create .htaccess and block UserAgent libwww-perl?

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis, .htaccess, useragent

I have been testing my website with a SEO checkup tool and one of the warnings I got was this:

> Your server appears to allow access from User-agent Libwww-perl.
>   Botnet scripts that automatically look for vulnerabilities in your
>   software are sometimes identified as User-Agent libwww-perl. By
>   blocking access from libwww-perl you can eliminate many simpler
>   attacks. Read more on blocking Libwww-perl access and improving your
>   website's security.

Afterwards I followed a guide on http://www.seositecheckup.com/articles/87 and created a `.htaccess` file via Notepad and added the following lines:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} libwww [NC,OR]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)=http [NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ – [F,L]
```

I then placed the `.htaccess` file in my website-root (beside my default.asp) and re-tested with the SEO tool. But the same warning comes up once again. Is there anyway for testing this myself or have I done anything wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You did not mention your web server name: apache, iis, or...

The `.htaccess` files can be used with apache and you have to include a directive like:

```
AllowOverride FileInfo
```

Without such a line, the `.htaccess` file will be ignored.

For the testing issue, you can use a firefox plugin called "User Agent Switcher". This enables you to type your own custom user agent.

Comment: Ah, it is IIS7. Which might be the reason for why it doesnt work :/

Comment: Have a look at this link: http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/557/translate-htaccess-content-to-iis-webconfig/

Answer (score 0):

You should use this code after "RewriteEngine On" roles in .htaccess :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} libwww-perl.*
RewriteRule .* – [F,L]
```

I use it and it Works!
Have a good time

Comment: The server required web.configs and not .htaccess - Look at the other answers + comments